# Print bold or colored text from Makefile rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnome-terminal, ansi-colors

I'm trying to print bold text from the following `Makefile` :

```
printf-bold-1:
    @printf "normal text - \e[1mbold text\e[0m"
```

But, escape sequences are printed as-is, so when running `make printf-bold-1`, I got :

> normal text - \e[1mbold text\e[0m

Instead of expected :

> normal text - **bold text**

It's weird because I can print bold text from my terminal : running directly command `printf "normal text - \e[1mbold text\e[0m"` produces, as expected :

> normal text - **bold text**

In the `Makefile`, I tried to use `@echo` or `echo` instead of `@printf`, or print `\x1b` instead of `\e`, but without success.

Here are some variables describing my environment (Linux with standard Gnome terminal), if that can help :

```
COLORTERM=gnome-terminal
TERM=xterm-256color
```

Note also that on some colleagues laptops (Mac), bold text is printed correctly.

What is the portable way, working on every environment, to print bold or colored text from a `Makefile` rule?

Comment: I highly recommend you use single quotes here, just for safety.  However, your first example worked fine for me (Ubuntu 18.04) in GNOME terminal and xterm.  You absolutely cannot use `echo` for this BTW.  I'm not sure exactly what you mean by using different shells: make doesn't care what shell you invoked it with.  It always uses `/bin/sh` unless you set the `SHELL` variable _in your makefile_ to something different.

Comment: When using simple quotes, bold text is correctly printed. I can't figure why, do you have an explanation? Thanks anyway! I'll remove the part about the shells from the question as it is misleading, I don't know why I wrote that.

Comment: It depends on if `printf` interprets \e as an escape sequence. `echo` does not without the option to tell it so: `echo -e "\e[1mbold\e[0m"`

Comment: @shawnhcorey Thanks, but I'm still not sure to understand why `printf` sometimes interpret `\e` as an escape sequence (like on my colleagues' Mac, or on @MadScientist environment) and sometimes not (my environment).

Comment: I can't explain why you see different behavior.  But I can explain why single vs. double quotes might make a difference: in single quotes the shell doesn't interpret the string at all before sending it to the program it runs (printf here).  In double quotes, the shell _does_ interpret that string looking for special characters such as `$`, backquotes, etc. so it can perform operations on them.  Backslash IS a special character, because it can escape things (like quotes) and the shell WILL interpret backslashes... sometimes.  Depends on the shell.

Comment: You're probably using a non-standard shell in your terminal - for example, Bash has a built-in `printf` that may be different to the one available in your `/bin/sh` (as used by Make unless otherwise overridden).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use the usual `tput` program for producing the correct escape sequences for the actual terminal, rather than hard-coding specific strings (that look ugly in an Emacs compilation buffer, for example):

```
printf-bold-1:
    @printf "normal text - `tput bold`bold text`tput sgr0`"

.PHONY: printf-bold-1
```

Of course, you may store the result into a Make variable, to reduce the number of subshells:

```
bold := $(shell tput bold)
sgr0 := $(shell tput sgr0)

printf-bold-1:
    @printf 'normal text - $(bold)bold text$(sgr0)'

.PHONY: printf-bold-1
```

---

You might even consider defining a function for styling output:

```
text-style = $(shell tput $1)$2$(shell tput sgr0)

printf-bold-1:
    @printf %s\\n 'normal text - $(call text-style,bold,bold text)'
    @echo '$(call text-style,setaf 1,red text)'

.PHONY: printf-bold-1
```

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I got it. I should have used `\033` instead of `\e` or `\x1b` :

```
printf-bold-1:
    @printf "normal text - \033[1mbold text\033[0m"
```

Or, as suggested in the comments, use simple quotes instead of double quotes :

```
printf-bold-1:
    @printf 'normal text - \e[1mbold text\e[0m'
```

`make printf-bold-1` now produces :

> normal text - **bold text**